# Alternative of ANY in Angular in HTTP

Tags: angular, typescript

In below code I want to remove any from Reponse. Nut sure how to do it.

```
this.constantsService.callServiceFunction(this.constantsService.getServiceConstant().ABCD_SERVER.GET_LIST)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe({
        next: (response: any) => {
        
        })
```

Please help me how I can get proper datatype instead of `any`.

This is response (instead of ANY):

```
export interface DashboardRoot {
    message: DashboardMessage
    response: DashboardResponse[]
}
```

Comment: please share the response by doing `console.log` and update it in the question!

Comment: also the contents of `callServiceFunction` sorry

Comment: If `this.constantsService.getServiceConstant().ABCD_SERVER.GET_LIST` is of type `DashboardRoot` and such defined, then you can omit `: any` from the subscription.

Comment: First try to get the data model of the response, either check the swagger or your network tab. Then make a type or interface with your data structure, then use it instead of `any`.

Comment: When you explicitly specify the parameter type of an inline callback function you are effectively performing an implicit type assertion which is not wise. If someone refactored that service to provide type information you would have just thrown it away with your `:any` annotation. You won't get a no implicit any error if you leave The annotation off because the compiler knows the type which is indeed `any`. In other words, this is bad code stop writing it.

Comment: you can use `next: (response: DashboardRoot ) =>{...}`, but this only help you to compile, Angular **not** make anything with the response. If it's not a "DasboardRoot" you don't know. Think that Angular "transpile" to javaScript, and in javaScript all the variables are "any"

Answer (score 0):

when implement method in constantsService

```
callServiceFunction(constant: ConstatntType):Observable<DashboardRoot>{
   // here after get tell angular what will be type that it will return<>
   return this.http.get<DashboardRoot>(...rest of youre code)
  }
```

after this response will be DashboardRoot type